# replacing a part of row name by sample name

Tags: filenames, replace

I have multiple samples named p1_500sc.fasta, p2_500sc.fasta...
Each file loks like this:

```
>NODE_60_length_504_cov_1.580902
TATATCGCCGTAGATAGACGAATACGGGATTTTGAAATGACTGATATATTCAAGCACATC
CTGTTCAGTCCAAAATGACATCGGCTTCGATTTCGGGATTGCCCCCGCAAAGTTGTTACA
>NODE_61_length_503_cov_4.457447
GATATGGGCCGGTGAGCATGCTGTCACATTTTGGGCAGGTGCCGAGGATTATGAGCTCGT
CTTCCGGCGTCAACGCTTGTTCGTTGCGTCTGGTGATGTGTTCCAGAGCGGCATAGTCGT
>NODE_62_length_500_cov_4.037534
CTCGTTCTTGCACTCCTGAATGAAGCGAATCTCTGACGAGGGTATTCCATAATCCTCTAT
CAGCTTACGCTTGATTTCTG
>NODE_63_length_500_cov_1.718499
GGAGGATATCAATGCCCTTATACTGCTTCTCAACAGTAGGAGTAATGCGGATACCCAAAA
CGGTCTTAGGGTTCTCCAGCAACTTCATGGCATTCCAACGCTTCAAGTCATCCATGCGGA
AGCCTTCGGCT
```

As You see always there is a NODE phrase. For each file I would like to change "NODE" for the file indicator from the sample's name: p1/ p2/ p100...pn

The output should look like this for file p1_500sc.fasta:

```
>p1_60_length_504_cov_1.580902
TATATCGCCGTAGATAGACGAATACGGGATTTTGAAATGACTGATATATTCAAGCACATC
CTGTTCAGTCCAAAATGACATCGGCTTCGATTTCGGGATTGCCCCCGCAAAGTTGTTACA
>p1_61_length_503_cov_4.457447
GATATGGGCCGGTGAGCATGCTGTCACATTTTGGGCAGGTGCCGAGGATTATGAGCTCGT
CTTCCGGCGTCAACGCTTGTTCGTTGCGTCTGGTGATGTGTTCCAGAGCGGCATAGTCGT
>p1_62_length_500_cov_4.037534
CTCGTTCTTGCACTCCTGAATGAAGCGAATCTCTGACGAGGGTATTCCATAATCCTCTAT
CAGCTTACGCTTGATTTCTG
>p1_63_length_500_cov_1.718499
GGAGGATATCAATGCCCTTATACTGCTTCTCAACAGTAGGAGTAATGCGGATACCCAAAA
CGGTCTTAGGGTTCTCCAGCAACTTCATGGCATTCCAACGCTTCAAGTCATCCATGCGGA
AGCCTTCGGCT
```

For p123_500sc.fasta file

```
>p123_2_length_456_cov_4.453333
GATATGGGCCGGTGAGCATGCTGTCACATTTTGGGCAGGTGCCGAGGATTATGAGCTCGT
CTTCCGGCGTCAACGCTTGTTCGTTGCGTCTGGTGATGTGTTCCAGAGCGGCATAGTCGT
>p123_356_length_3_cov_4.037908
CTCGTTCTTGCACTCCTGAATGAAGCGAATCTCTGACGAGGGTATTCCATAATCCTCTAT
CAGCTTACGCTTGATTTCTG
```

The same for any other sample. Sample  start from p1, and they can reach p150.

Answer (score 2):

**`bash`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
for f in p[0-9]*.fasta; do
    pfx="${f%%_*}"
    sed -i "s/^>NODE/>$pfx/" "$f"
done
```

---

- `pfx="${f%%_*}"` - truncate the right part of the filename till the last `_` ; assign the result to variable `pfx`
- `sed -i "s/^>NODE/>$pfx/"` - substitute `>NODE` substring with `$pfx` variable in-place

Comment: Should i create .sh script? How to run it. Sorry for asking but I am a begginer.

Comment: Place it into shell script for multiline version. For throw-away one-liner - just run `for f in p[0-9]*.fasta; do pfx="${f%%_*}"; sed -i "s/^>NODE/>$pfx/" "$f"; done` in the command line

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you can do it in a single command invocation:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '
  BEGINFILE {
    node = FILENAME
    sub(".*/", "", node)
    sub("_.*", "", node)
  }
  $1 == ">NODE" {$1 = ">" node}
  {print}' ./p*_*.fasta
```

In any case, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Comment: some shorter one: `gawk -i inplace -F_ -v OFS=_ 'BEGINFILE {
    node = FILENAME;
    gsub(/.*\/|_.*/, "", node)
  }$1 == ">NODE"{ $1 = ">" node }1' ./p*_*.fasta`

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through each file, assign the everything before the underscore in the filename to the variable `sample`, then subsitute `>NODE` for `$sample` in the file using `sed`:

```
for file in /path/to/files/*;do
  sample=$(echo "${file}" | sed s/_.*//)
  sed -i "s/^>NODE/${sample}/" ${file}
done
```